# Error: Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c++, function-pointers, rvalue, mbed

I started receiving this error when I used the class InterruptIn in MBED.
This is the definition of the `fall` function that I'm trying to call:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
   void Sensor::contador(int cont){
          cont++;
   }  
   int Sensor::medidaSensor(){
    //Se activa el watchdog:
       Timer timer;
       timer.start();
       int npulsos=0;
       while(1){
           //Cuenta los pulsos durante 5ms
           if (timer.read_ms() < 5)
           {
              vcomp.fall(&contador(npulsos)); // <= compilation error here
           }
           else{
               //Kick the watchdog to reset its timer
                watchdogTimer.kick();
           }
       }
       return npulsos;
   }
```

Comment: `contador()` returns `void`, so `&contador(npulsos)` returns one rvalue of `void` type and you are trying to get the address. What are you trying to pass to `fall` function?

Comment: `void` means no value, not `object without value`. Also please post the definition of `fall` as text, not as image (read https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 2):

From your `fall` definition

- obj - pointer to the object to call the member function on
- method - pointer to the member function to be called

I think you want:

```
vcomp.fall(this, &Sensor::contador);
```

i.e. call the contador method on the current object.

Note however that this does not accept a parameter for the callback member function, therefore you can't call your current contador method: you'll have to make the count a field in the class instead, or e.g. use a different fall() signature such as the one that accepts a callback function. (My C++ lamdas are rusty I'm afraid so I'm not sure if you could replicate this using a lambda with a closure as you could in other languages, or if that would cause problems with the lifetime of the lambda.)

And in any case in the [latest version of the documentation](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.15/mbed-os-api-doxy/classmbed_1_1_interrupt_in.html#a7c26533065ddeafeb6ed293b752790e8) this version of the fall method is marked deprecated in favour of the callback version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to call to fall function (based on the picture that you have attached) we dont know what this function do but neverminds:

```
  void Sensor::contador(int* cont){
          ++(*cont);
   }  
   int Sensor::medidaSensor(){
    //Se activa el watchdog:
       Timer timer;
       timer.start();
       int npulsos=0;
       while(1){
           //Cuenta los pulsos durante 5ms
           if (timer.read_ms() < 5)
           {
              vcomp.fall(this,Sensor::contador);
           }
           else{
               //Kick the watchdog to reset its timer
                watchdogTimer.kick();
           }
       }
       return npulsos;
   }
```

Comment: It's probably not `&npulsos` as that's an int and doesn't have member functions. It should be the address of a `Sensor` (i.e. `this`)

Comment: Maybe! this ambiguous and confusing. maybe T* object (from fall function) its a prameter (context) to M method to operate on. so there is nothing wrong in my answer i think . 
Anyway you would agree with me that this problem is ambiguous

Comment: It's not ambiguous; you cannot call a member function on an `int`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings- I rushed, and missed the small words in the attached picture: "obj - pointer to the object to call the member function on" - so absolutley its the object (this) itself. my mistake i will fix my answer. thanks. (please push the vote up again)

Comment: That's right. This is a common C-style callback pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately your code still won't compile, since `contador` expects an argument. Rup has the full answer.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I agree with you!@Rup described it better than me!